# can't seem to resolve watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s.. from nvidia

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have 1060 gtx with 515 nvidia drivers with 2 monitors 1 primary is connected to my gpu and the other secondary to the mobo GA-Z87X-UD4H.

everything was working perfect with the drivers since I installed ubuntu in july until today...
I turned on my computer today and my primary monitor turns off and the screen transfer to the secondary monitor where it's displaying:
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s.. errors
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s.. errors
...
when I enter in recovery mode, only my primary monitor is active and the secondary monitor is not detected...

I uninstalled nvidia driver and then both monitors work fine so I tried to reinstall the driver and I get he same bug again..

Please help I am not sure what to do

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What is the kernel? How did you install Nvidia drivers?